# New API update is returning codes BADDEBT, CAPIMPORTS, CIUINPUT which do not match the API statuses for TaxType or ReportTaxType

Tags: xero-api

In our live enivonment when we're getting tax rates for some of our customers, we're getting at least 3 codes back (BADDEBT, CAPIMPORTS, CIUINPUT) which do not map up to either https://github.com/XeroAPI/Xero-NetStandard/blob/master/Xero.NetStandard.OAuth2/Model/Accounting/TaxType.cs or the enum ReportTaxTypeEnum inside https://github.com/XeroAPI/Xero-NetStandard/blob/master/Xero.NetStandard.OAuth2/Model/Accounting/TaxRate.cs

This is causing some major issues and we can't figure out where theses codes are coming from

Comment: These are new system tax rates for customers in South Africa. We've not yet rolled them out across out OpenAPI spec and SDKs but will do so asap

Comment: As of version 2.2.2 of our OpenAPI specs, we have added new South Africa tax report types.  Watch for the next release of the .NET Standard SDK.

https://github.com/XeroAPI/Xero-OpenAPI

Comment: Thank you both for fixing the issue and the quick response